# How to do video testing from web application?

Tags: html, media-player

I have web application which contains 1000s of videos, for testing purpose I have to manually check each and every video. Is there any tool available for video testing which can ease my job?

Answer (score 0):

If the videos you want to test with have some sort of pattern and you have the list of videos you want to test. One way to automate this is to use Ghost Inspector (Automated website testing). Thus, you would create a test in GI (Ghost Inspector) for one video, then call the GI test via it's execute API passing in different video ids to GI. Then you could run it on a schedule.

Note there has to be something common that changes about the videos when it plays so you can make a repeatable test in Ghost Inspector.

These links should help you get the information you need to create what you want:

GI Getting Started: https://ghostinspector.com/docs/getting-started/

GI Execute API: https://ghostinspector.com/docs/api/tests/#execute

GI Scheduling: 
https://ghostinspector.com/docs/test-schedule/

Comment: You can do this solely with Ghost Inspector, don't need to use us (Runscope) for the dynamic data or scheduling. Pass in dynamic data via calls to the execute API: https://ghostinspector.com/docs/api/tests/#execute

Comment: Thanks John for the clarification on this, I updated my answer.